# Breadcrumbs for a view page with arguments

Tags: views

How do I set the breadcrumbs for a view page with arguments? I've used the "User: username" argument, and the following PHP Code as default argument, but it doesn't work:

```
$breadcrumb[] = l('Home', NULL);
$breadcrumb[] .= l('Our Team', 'team');
drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
```

Comment: please tag your question with the version of drupal you are using (and also views)

Answer (score 1):

I believe when you are creating a view that has an argument you can the opportunity to set a breadcrumb from within views itself.

Substitutions will also be available based on the arguments present.

For example, if you view is

```
/blogs/2011
```

Where blogs is the path to the page, and 2011 is the argument, you could set the breadcrumb of the page with the argument to be:

```
%1
```

This would leave breadcrumbs that would look like:

```
Blogs > 2011
```

Comment: I already did that, but it returns no breadcrumbs at all :(

Comment: Don't suppose you are messing with hook_breadcrumb()? You will be able to do this without touching that hook

Comment: I only use this in template.php:

function phptemplate_breadcrumb($breadcrumb) {
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    return '<div class="breadcrumb">'. implode(' → ', $breadcrumb) .'</div>';
  }
}

does it interfere with views arguments?

Comment: You may want to check the menu settings for the views display at "/blogs".

Comment: Also, I think views only builds a breadcrumb from all but the last item. E.g. if you visit the page /blogs/2011/05/22, then the breadcrumb will only be Blogs > 2011 > 05, without the last item. See https://drupal.org/node/1919456#comment-7439094

Comment: (seeing this issue is 2 years old, but it may still have visitors from search)